# Share icon doesn't work on every device

Tags: android, device

I have share icon in my app which allows to share images on facebook,whatsapp,twitter etc.I tested it in three mobile devices it works fine on one mobile device but doesn't open anything on other two..Here is the code i am calling on clicking on share icon..What is the reason that it works fine on one device and not on other two..Is it coding issue or some device problem?I am using API 19 mobile device

```
if (lActionBtnTag.startsWith(G.General.TAG_SHARE))
            {

                aView.setEnabled(false);
                actionHandler.shareG(gMoments.get(lPosition), aView);
            }
  public void shareG(final GMoment aGMoment, final View aShareBtn)
    {
        try {

            String lMediaType = aGMoment.getGMediaType();
            if (lMediaType.equals(G.General.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO) || lMediaType.equals(G.General.MEDIA_TYPE_MEME))
            {
                _handleImageShare(aGMoment, aShareBtn);

            }
            else if (lMediaType.equals(Guggu.General.MEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO))
            {

            }
            else if (lMediaType.equals(Guggu.General.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO))
            {

            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(G.Tag, "Exception saving image to share: " + aGMoment.getGMediaLoc(), ex);
        }
    }
    private void _handleImageShare(final GMoment aGMoment, final View aShareBtn)
        {

            final String lShareableFileName = "xyz.jpg";
            imageLoader.get(aGMoment.getGMediaLoc(), new ImageLoader.ImageListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer imageContainer, boolean b) {

                    try {
                        FileOutputStream outputStream = mCtxt.getApplicationContext().openFileOutput(lShareableFileName,
                                Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

                        Bitmap lBmp = imageContainer.getBitmap();

                        if (lBmp != null) {
                            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            lBmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, stream);
                            byte[] imageInByte = stream.toByteArray();
                            stream.close();

                            ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageInByte);
                            IOUtils.copy(in, outputStream);
                            outputStream.close();
                            in.close();

                            aShareBtn.setEnabled(true);
                            _launchShareIntents(lShareableFileName, aGMoment.getDescription());
                        }
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        // TODO: Log this exception
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                    aShareBtn.setEnabled(true);
                    Log.e(Guggu.Tag, volleyError.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }

        private void _launchShareIntents(String aImgPath, String aDesc)
        {

            String lSelectedIntent;
            List<Intent> intentList = new ArrayList<Intent>();

            final PackageManager mgr = mCtxt.getPackageManager();
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");

            List<ResolveInfo> list = mgr.queryIntentActivities(sendIntent, 0);

            for (ResolveInfo info : list) {
                lSelectedIntent = info.activityInfo.packageName;

                if (lSelectedIntent.contains("twitter") || lSelectedIntent.contains("facebook") || lSelectedIntent.contains("whatsapp"))
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(lSelectedIntent, info.activityInfo.name));
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    intent.setType("image/*");

                    if (lSelectedIntent.contains("twitter") || lSelectedIntent.contains("whatsapp"))
                    {
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, aDesc);
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(mCtxt.getFileStreamPath(aImgPath)));

                    }
                    else if (lSelectedIntent.contains("facebook"))
                    {
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(mCtxt.getFileStreamPath(aImgPath)));
                    }

                    intentList.add(new LabeledIntent(intent, lSelectedIntent, info.loadLabel(mgr), info.icon));
                }
            }

            if (intentList == null && intentList.size() == 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            Intent  openInChooser = Intent.createChooser(intentList.remove(0), "Share this image");
            openInChooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentList.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));

            mCtxt.startActivity(openInChooser);
        }
```

Intent.java

```
public static Intent createChooser(Intent target, CharSequence title) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_CHOOSER);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_INTENT, target);
        if (title != null) {
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TITLE, title);
        }
        // Migrate any clip data and flags from target.
        int permFlags = target.getFlags() & (FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                | FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION
                | FLAG_GRANT_PREFIX_URI_PERMISSION);
        if (permFlags != 0) {
            ClipData targetClipData = target.getClipData();
            if (targetClipData == null && target.getData() != null) {
                ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item(target.getData());
                String[] mimeTypes;
                if (target.getType() != null) {
                    mimeTypes = new String[] { target.getType() };
                } else {
                    mimeTypes = new String[] { };
                }
                targetClipData = new ClipData(null, mimeTypes, item);
            }
            if (targetClipData != null) {
                intent.setClipData(targetClipData);
                intent.addFlags(permFlags);
            }
        }

        return intent;
    }
```

Comment: are you sure all the devices you are installing you application on have a Sharing application installed? do they actually have facebook installed etc?

Comment: @Hector they don't have all Sharing application installed but they do have some sharing application installed..

Comment: can you post the code from your application where you create the sharing INTENT then?

Comment: @Hector posted in question...hope tht is what u asked for..